# Dropdown not working in fullcalendar cell

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Drop down not working in full calendar cell. This is my code http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/1454/

in this when click on the dropdown the options not coming

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
    editable: true,
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {  

        return $('<div>' + event.title + '</div>');  
    },

    events: [
        {
            title: '<select id="drp"><option>Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="opel">Opel</option><option value="audi">Audi</option></select>',
            start: '2014-06-01'
        },
        {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2014-06-07',
            end: '2014-06-10'
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2014-06-09T16:00:00'
        },
    ]
});
```

Comment: At least provide relevant jsFiddle...

Comment: This is updated js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/1454/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider it a bug in fullcalendar. It is this code that is stealing the click:

```
    element
        .mousedown(function(ev) { // prevent native <a> selection for others
            ev.preventDefault();
        })
        .click(function(ev) {
            if (isResizing) {
                ev.preventDefault(); // prevent link from being visited (only method that worked in IE6)
                ev.stopImmediatePropagation(); // prevent fullcalendar eventClick handler from being called
                                               // (eventElementHandlers needs to be bound after resizableDayEvent)
            }
        });
```

As a workaround, you can set `editable: false`, `resizable: false`.

As a solution, you can call this on your dropdown once fullcalendar is fully initialized, to prevent the click/mousedown from reaching the div.ui-draggable where the offending handler is attached.

```
$("#drp").on("mousedown click", function(event){event.stopPropagation()});
```